# Update datagridview cell value using SqlCommand in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview fro my application.I want to update the datagridview column value using `SqlCommand`, I have a code for that, but it is showing error. How could I do it?

Here is my update button code:

```
private void EDIT(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrid.Rows)
    {
        if (datagrid.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int nRowIndex = datagrid.Rows.Count - 2;

            if (datagrid.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null)
            { 
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd11 = new SqlCommand("update Purchasedetail set qty=@qty ,price=@price,tax=@tax,discount=@discount,total=@total where product_id=@product_id, product_name=@product_name", con);

                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", row.Cells[0].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_name", row.Cells[1].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", row.Cells[2].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", row.Cells[3].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tax", row.Cells[4].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", row.Cells[5].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", row.Cells[6].Value);

                cmd11.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully", "OUTPUT", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly and on which line? Are you sure your `SqlConnection` is `Open`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** Youare not closing the `SqlCommand` object properly in a loop.

**Solution 1:** You need to `close` the `SqlCommand` object properly while executing in a loop.

You need to enclose it in the `using block {}`

```
using(SqlCommand cmd11 = new SqlCommand("update command"))
{

}
```

**Problem 2:** You are returning from the function after executing the first command so you are not actually executing the command for all rows(only for one row).is it intension to update only one row?

**Solution 2:** if your intension is to update only one row you need to remove the return statement

**Problem 3:** You are just displaying the Success Messagewithout even checking wether the update is successfull or not.

**Solution 3:** You need to ensure that wether all of the rows updated successfully or not before displaying the Success Message.

**Complete Code:**

```
private void EDIT(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    bool UpdateFailed = false;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrid.Rows)
    {
        if (datagrid.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int nRowIndex = datagrid.Rows.Count - 2;

            if (datagrid.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null)
            { 

               using(SqlCommand cmd11 = new SqlCommand("update Purchasedetail set 
                     qty=@qty ,price=@price,tax=@tax,discount=@discount,total=@total
                     where product_id=@product_id, product_name=@product_name", con))
               {
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", row.Cells[0].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_name", row.Cells[1].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", row.Cells[2].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", row.Cells[3].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tax", row.Cells[4].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", row.Cells[5].Value);
                cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", row.Cells[6].Value);

                 if(!Convert.ToInt32(cmd11.ExecuteNonQuery()) > 0)
                     UpdateFailed = true;
               }


            }
        }
    }
      if(!UpdateFailed)
           MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully", "OUTPUT", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                         MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: That's not the case anymore. OP added this line and still there is an error.

Comment: @SonerGönül: it was not there before so i tought it could be the issue, Anyways Thanks

Comment: This code is well,but i want to update only selected row